# Error alert JS: 403 Forbidden en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un problema en una web de wordpress, en cada página de producto, al entrar sale un alert mostrando un error 403 Forbidden. Viene del archivo admin-ajax.php
En Internet Explorer y en Mobile sale casi siempre.

No consigo averiguar de dónde viene. Puede ser problema de permisos, htaccess... pero he probado de todo.

[Ver imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFhMp.jpg)

Una url de ejemplo:  http://www.vadepizzapark.com/producto/pizza-fondue/

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El motivo del error 403 es que no está enviando encabezados. Como está realizando una solicitud de CORS, no puede enviar ningún encabezado personalizado a menos que el servidor habilite estos encabezados añadiendo `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` a la respuesta.

En una solicitud preseleccionada, el cliente realiza 2 solicitudes al servidor. El primero es la verificación previa (con el método OPTION) y el segundo es la solicitud real. El servidor envía el encabezado Access-Control-Allow-Headers como respuesta a la solicitud de verificación previa. Por lo tanto, permite el envío de algunos encabezados. De esta manera, su solicitud POST puede funcionar, porque la solicitud POST es una solicitud previa. Pero para una solicitud GET, no hay verificación previa para reunir el encabezado Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Entonces, el navegador no envía tus encabezados personalizados.

**Una solucion:**

Agregar en su archivo php `admin-ajax.php` antes de imprimir cualquier cosa con el, ejemplo:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que va bien!

- Añadí al functions.php:

add_filter('allowed_http_origins', 'add_allowed_origins');

function add_allowed_origins($origins) {
    $origins[] = 'http://www.URL.com';
    return $origins;
}

-Añadí al .htaccess:

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Y actualicé de nuevo los plugins.

Alguna de las 3 resultó :)

Gracias